# Calculating the number of days before a date with a certain number of events in R

Tags: r, date, calculation

I have a dataset with a date and a number of events:

```
    date    number_of_events
1/14/2013   1
2/6/2013    1
6/5/2013    1
7/1/2013    2
7/15/2013   1
7/19/2013   1
8/1/2013    2
```

I want to calculate how many days until the date when the number of events is 2 (or any other pre-determined value).

This is my goal...

```
date    number_of_events    days_to_two_events
1/14/2013   1               168
2/6/2013    1               145
6/5/2013    1               26
7/1/2013    2               31
7/15/2013   1               17
7/19/2013   1               13
8/1/2013    2               0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `zoo`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "date    number_of_events
1/14/2013   1
2/6/2013    1
6/5/2013    1
7/1/2013    2
7/15/2013   1
7/19/2013   1
8/1/2013    2", header= T)


library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(days_to_two_events = na.locf0(ifelse(lead(number_of_events, 1) == 2, lead(date, 1), NA), fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(days_to_two_events = as.Date(days_to_two_events, format = "%m/%d/%Y")-as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are two solutions which use a *backward rolling join*.

The two solutions differ in the way the day difference is computed for rows with `number_of_events == 2`. The first solution computes the day difference with respect to the next row  with `number_of_events == 2` *including itself*. So, `days_to_two_events` is zero in this case.

The second solution computes the day difference with respect to the next row  with `number_of_events == 2` *excluding itself*. So, for a row with `number_of_events == 2` it looks for the day difference to the *subsequent* row  with `number_of_events == 2`. This is the expected result.

Both variants assume that `df` is already ordered by `date`.

#### First variant

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date := lubridate::mdy(date)]
df[number_of_events == 2][
  df, on = "date", roll = -Inf, 
  .(date, number_of_events = i.number_of_events, days_to_two_events = x.date - date)]
```

> ```
>          date number_of_events days_to_two_events
> 1: 2013-01-14                1           168 days
> 2: 2013-02-06                1           145 days
> 3: 2013-06-05                1            26 days
> 4: 2013-07-01                2             0 days
> 5: 2013-07-15                1            17 days
> 6: 2013-07-19                1            13 days
> 7: 2013-08-01                2             0 days
> ```

#### Second variant (expected result)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date := lubridate::mdy(date)]
df[number_of_events == 2][
  df, on = "date", roll = -Inf, 
  .(date, number_of_events = i.number_of_events, 
    days_to_two_events = shift(x.date, -1, fill = last(x.date)) - date)]
```

> ```
>          date number_of_events days_to_two_events
> 1: 2013-01-14                1           168 days
> 2: 2013-02-06                1           145 days
> 3: 2013-06-05                1            26 days
> 4: 2013-07-01                2            31 days
> 5: 2013-07-15                1            17 days
> 6: 2013-07-19                1            13 days
> 7: 2013-08-01                2             0 days
> ```

Note the difference between the two solutions in row 4.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(text = "date    number_of_events
1/14/2013   1
2/6/2013    1
6/5/2013    1
7/1/2013    2
7/15/2013   1
7/19/2013   1
8/1/2013    2")
```